# Mysql - Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a DB schema as such,

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema stack_vista
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema stack_vista
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `stack_vista` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `stack_vista` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `stack_vista`.`csv`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stack_vista`.`csv` (
  `idcsv` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serviceCode` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `offerDate` DATETIME NULL,
  `price` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `offerDuration` INT NULL,
  `occupancy` INT NULL,
  `extra_cols` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcsv`),
  INDEX `index_service_code` (`serviceCode` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `stack_vista`.`offers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stack_vista`.`offers` (
  `idoffers` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shipSlug` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `offerLink` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `serviceCode` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `extra_cols` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idoffers`),
  INDEX `index_offer_code` (`serviceCode` ASC),
  FULLTEXT INDEX `index_ship_slug` (`shipSlug` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `stack_vista`.`ships`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stack_vista`.`ships` (
  `idships` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idships`),
  FULLTEXT INDEX `index_slug` (`slug` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `stack_vista`.`props`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stack_vista`.`props` (
  `idprops` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idoffers` INT NOT NULL,
  `propName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `propCode` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idprops`),
  INDEX `fk_props_offers_idx` (`idoffers` ASC),
  INDEX `index_type` (`type` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_props_offers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idoffers`)
    REFERENCES `stack_vista`.`offers` (`idoffers`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `stack_vista`.`location`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stack_vista`.`location` (
  `idlocation` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `code` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlocation`),
  INDEX `index_type` (`type` ASC),
  INDEX `index_name` (`name` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `stack_vista`.`offers_has_location`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stack_vista`.`offers_has_location` (
  `offers_idoffers` INT NOT NULL,
  `location_idlocation` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`offers_idoffers`, `location_idlocation`),
  INDEX `fk_offers_has_location_location1_idx` (`location_idlocation` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_offers_has_location_offers1_idx` (`offers_idoffers` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_offers_has_location_offers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`offers_idoffers`)
    REFERENCES `stack_vista`.`offers` (`idoffers`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_offers_has_location_location1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_idlocation`)
    REFERENCES `stack_vista`.`location` (`idlocation`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

My table `csv` is a table where I add data imported from csv, and has offers for different services/travels, for different dates, location and types. It can have 10000-100000 records, with around 900-1000 services and it's combination as seen in `group by`.

Different services maps to `servicCode` from table `offers`, which is unique in `offers` table.

Some of the `offers` have `shipSlugs`, which maps to `slugs` in `ships` table.

> I am trying to list all possible `serviceCodes`, `offerDate`,
>   `propTypeId`, and `shipSlug`. Since there are further factors for
>   example, `csv.extra_cols` and `csv.offerDuration` which affects the
>   price, I just wanted to get `MIN(Price)` based on columns used in
>   `GROUP BY` hence the aggregation.

I have added index in every columns which is involved either in where clause or join on conditions.

My query below currently takes between 6-9 seconds to execute. What can be further done to optimize this query:

```
SELECT 
    i.serviceCode AS serviceCode,
    i.offerDate AS offerDate,
    MIN(i.price) AS price,
    i.offerDuration AS duration,
    i.occupancy AS occupancy,
    p.idprops AS propTypeId,
    p.propName AS propTypeName,
    p.propCode AS propTypeCode,
    p.type AS type,
    g.idlocation AS destinationId,
    g.name AS destinationName,
    g.code AS destinationCode,
    g.type AS destinationType,
    o.idoffers AS offerId,
    o.offerlink AS offerlink,
    o.name AS name,
    o.shipSlug AS shipSlug,
    s.name AS shipName,
    CONCAT_WS('-',
            YEAR(i.offerDate),
            MONTH(i.offerDate)) AS offer_year_month_date
FROM
    csv i
        JOIN
    offers o ON o.serviceCode = i.serviceCode
        LEFT JOIN
    ships s ON o.shipSlug = s.slug
        JOIN
    props p ON o.idoffers = p.idoffers
        JOIN
    offers_has_location og ON o.idoffers = og.offers_idoffers
        JOIN
    location g ON g.idlocation = og.location_idlocation
WHERE
    p.type = 'travelType'
        AND g.code IN ('Earth' , 'River', 'HighLands')
GROUP BY serviceCode, offer_year_month_date, propTypeId, shipSlug;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this query makes sense due to how you are using GROUP BY.

Comment: @lurker MSSQL <> MySQL, that topic is totally not related.. Also SQL tag on this website does not mean MSSQL ...

Comment: @paul you're right actually, it's from another part. I've edited it.

Comment: You still have `MIN(i.price)`.

Comment: Agree with Paul.  You have a MIN() which is an aggregate based on some grouping.  Are you trying to get the minimum price based on an offering, an offering for a date + service, offering date + service + something else?  Otherwise you will return one row and not necessarily get what you are hoping for.  As for SQL.  Is it really MySQL specifically?  Just trying to confirm.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yep, my bad on both points. Comment removed.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I am confused actually, I'm most likely wrong but can you please explain why my use of GROUP BY was wrong in the first place?

Comment: @DRapp yes I am trying to list all possible offers for `offerDate`, `propTypeId`, and `shipSlug` actually. Since there are further factors for example, `csv.extra_cols` and `csv.offerDuration` which affects the price, I just wanted to get `MIN(Price)` based on columns used in `GROUP BY` hence the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

One simple note, if the column name is the same as the result AS, you dont need the AS.  Only if you are changing the column name result, or result of some function such as your min/max, concat_ws, etc.

As for the group by.  You need to include all non-aggregate columns as part of a group by for it to not throw an error.  So, things that are ex: lookup descriptions that will never change per their corresponding id, you could use min() or max(). Another approach would be to pre-aggregate all except the lookup code descriptions keeping the IDs, THEN join to get lookup descriptions.

You are looking for a specific type and code, I would try to optimize starting with that.  I have also restructured the query and with MySQL am using the "STRAIGHT_JOIN" clause which tells the engine to run the query in the order I told you.

Now, I have made all non-group by columns with MIN() so the query will properly get the minimum price per prop type, service code, ship, year/month.  But it looks more like travel agency activity with different originations / destinations.  Without seeing more realistic sample data, I think these MIN() applications on other elements wont make sense.  You might need more than that.  Ex: a cruise based on single occupancy would obviously be less than double-occupancy.  So having the occupancy as part of the group would make sense.  A trip from port A to B would be totally different than port A to C, so origination and destinations I would expect would be part of the group by as well.

I think you really need to assert your data on what you are asking to truly make sense with your output.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      p.idprops AS propTypeId,
      o.serviceCode,
      o.shipSlug,
      CONCAT_WS('-',
         YEAR(i.offerDate),
         MONTH(i.offerDate)) AS offer_year_month_date,
      min(i.offerDate ) FirstOfferDate,
      min(i.price) AS price,
      min(i.offerDuration ) AS MinDuration,
      min( i.occupancy ) MinOccupancy,
      min( p.propName ) AS propTypeName,
      min( p.propCode ) AS propTypeCode,
      min( p.type ) as type,
      min( g.idlocation ) AS destinationId,
      min( g.name ) AS destinationName,
      min( g.code ) AS destinationCode,
      min( g.type ) AS destinationType,
      min( o.idoffers ) AS offerId,
      min( o.offerlink ) AS offerlink,
      min( o.name ),
      min( s.name ) AS shipName
   FROM
      props p 
        JOIN offers o
           ON p.idoffers = o.idoffers 
           JOIN csv i
              ON o.serviceCode = i.serviceCode
           LEFT JOIN
              ships s ON o.shipSlug = s.slug
        JOIN offers_has_location og 
           ON p.idoffers = og.offers_idoffers
           JOIN location g 
              ON og.location_idlocation = g.idlocation
             AND g.code IN ('Earth' , 'River', 'HighLands')
   WHERE
      p.type = 'travelType'
   GROUP BY 
      serviceCode, offer_year_month_date, propTypeId, shipSlug;
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see my mistakes and what Paul meant above. This does help me get what I am trying to get. However, this doesn't help with query optimization.

Comment: @roko, your query does not appear to lend itself to a higher optimization because of the other lookup / detail descriptions that don't make sense to optimizing.  However, I know that STRAIGHT_JOIN under many instances I have offered in the past have significantly improved query results from a server hanging and not returning anything to getting results back very quickly.

Comment: *"This does help me get what I am trying to get. However, this doesn't help with query optimization. "* @roko see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  ... You can get the  MIN/MAX per group  in a SQL query with a self left join with a shifting filter **without** the use off `GROUP BY/MIN()-MAX()`.  The data example and expected results are needed for SQL query rewrites..

Answer (score 0):

Some minor tips:

Instead of

```
s.name AS shipname
...
LEFT JOIN ships...
```

do

```
( SELECT name FROM ships ... ) AS shipname
```

And that table needs `INDEX(slug, name)`.  Hmmm...  Isn't this table a one-to-one mapping between `slug` and `name`??  If so, toss `idships` and have

```
PRIMARY KEY(slug),
UNIQUE(ships),
FULLTEXT(ships)
```

I don't see other cases for avoiding the bloat of `JOINs` followed by the deflation of `GROUP BY`.